# Cartan involution for finite W-algebras

Tags: w-algebras, lie-algebras, rt.representation-theory

Does anybody know if there is an analog of the Cartan (anti)involution for W-algebra
associated to a nilpotent element e, which is principal in some Levi subalgebra
of semi-simple Lie algebra g? Actually, I am more interested whether there exists an analog of the Shapovalov form on a Verma module for such a W-algebra.

Answer (score 2):

In the affine case, there is a related discussion in a paper by Kac-Wakimoto; 
see pp. 23-25 in arXiv:math-ph/0304011v2.